# What is the meaning of Conan Revision on Conan Center?

Tags: c++, conan

On Conan Center, there are 6 revisions of `boost/1.79.0`, but when I look at the *"List of available binary packages"* section, I can see a list longer than 6. Each binary package contains a unique set of settings, aka revisions. What is meant by Revision 6?

[image]

https://conan.io/center/boost?tab=configuration&os=Linux

Comment: Why `swift-package-manager` tag?

Comment: This revisions are something different the "List of available packages". Why do you think this is the same thing? If you click "Revisions" there are 6 items to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisions are changes to the recipe itself (i.e. changes to the conanfile.py or other parts of the recipe). The revisions will be to fix bugs, add more options or add newer versions of boost. You can see the changes at https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/commits/master/recipes/boost

Each revision of the recipe is then built with multiple settings and platforms to produce many binary packages.

Comment: How does conan know which package id I need as per my default profile settings?

Comment: @TonyParker you should ask a new question